# Dockerfile for a fastAPI app using Factory pattern with unicorn

Tags: docker, gunicorn, uvicorn

I am building a back-end service for a full-stack application using fastAPI and unicorn.

**src/asgi.py**

```
import uvicorn
from src import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", log_level="info", reload=True)
```

**src/**init**.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from src.api.v1.auth import auth_router
from src.core.config import *


def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    root_app = FastAPI()
    root_app.include_router(
        auth_router,
        prefix="/api/v1",
        tags=["auth"],
    )
    return root_app
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y postgresql-client

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

How I am building and running:

```
docker build -t travian-back:v1 . 
travian-back:v1 uvicorn asgi:app
```

There is no error at all, server is up at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`
Now I am trying to directly add the `uvicorn asgi:app` command to my `Dockerfile`. The reason is because I am going to use `docker-compose` at the end and it would be easier. This is what I have now:

**Dockerfile**

```
    RUN mkdir /app
    WORKDIR /app
    
    RUN apt update && \
        apt install -y postgresql-client
    
    COPY requirements.txt ./
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
    
    COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "asgi:app"]
```

Now instead of doing `travian-front:v1 uvicorn asgi:app` I am doing `travian-back:v1 uvicorn asgi:app` , I have no error when building and running my docker image but the server can't be reached at `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: What is the string `travian-front:v1 unicorn asgi:app`?  What are the actual `docker run` commands you're using in the various situations?  Where are you trying to reference the special 127.0.0.1 IP address?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my post because there is actually no `travian-front:v1 unicorn asgi:app`  at all and it should be  `travian-back:v1 unicorn asgi:app`   instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you don't run the asgi file as main, since you use uvicorn to point to it. So it's not listening on 0.0.0.0 or better put, all those options are ignored.

Either invoke the asgi file directly, which I would not recommend, or drop the asgi file and use uvicorn with the --factory flag and point it to your app factory.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "src.init:create_app", "--factory", "--host 0.0.0.0"]
```

I am using entrypoint here so that you can pass additional flags such as log level on run without overriding this.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 myapp --log-level warning
```

That said, I am somewhat confused by your file name init.py. Do you mean `__init__.py`? If so I would not put the factory in this file, `__init__.py` is not meant to be used like this. Put it in a file named main.py or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, it’s actually `__init__.py`, I have just updated my post

Comment: But what’s the best way to create a factory with a FastAPI object? I did a couple of apps using Flask and it was much more easier to create a factory

Comment: like you did, just dont put it in `__init__.py`. The `__init__.py` has a different purpose and should rarely contain code. Only for very specific reasons.

Comment: For the `__init__` my idea came from this article which is for Flask but I applied the same logic for FastAPI : https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory/

Comment: Notice there's no app.py, main.py, or anything of the sort in our base directory. Instead, the entirety of our app lives in the /application folder, with the creation of our app happening in __init__.py. The init file is where we actually create what's called the Application Factory.

Comment: I think you are right, it doesn’t seems logic to have code like this in the __init__.py